# Getting "Type of expression is ambiguous without context" when using list inside of VStack

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

So I'm using a List view inside of a VStack and am getting an issue saying "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". The issue started popping up when I began populating data via Firestore instead of just hardcoded values. I've simplified my code to show the structure of how I'm using the list below.

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore

struct MainView: View {
    
    @State private var radius = 300
    private var name = "Name"
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = TaskViewModel()
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    init() { UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UITableView.appearance().isScrollEnabled = false
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return NavigationView(content: {
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 150)
                
                List(viewModel.task) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Image(systemName: item.completedIcon)
                        Text(item.title).font(Font.custom("Permanent Marker", size: 18))
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle("Tasks")
                .onAppear() {
                    self.viewModel.fetchData()
                }
                .frame(width: 318, height: 404, alignment: .center)
                .shadow(radius: 7)
                .cornerRadius(25.0)
                .listRowBackground(Color.white)

            }
            
        })
        
    }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: You need to provide more details about viewModel.task. Most likely your issue is at `List(viewModel.taks)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here

```
List(viewModel.taks)
```

Make sure your custom model conforms to

```
struct Task:Identifiable {
```

or add id property

```
List(viewModel.taks, id: \.id) { item in
```

Comment: Ohh. Yes I didn't make the Task identifiable. Why is the id important for a list though, if you don't mind explaining?

Comment: its a way to make a loop valid either id or identifiable

Comment: @DayemSaeed SwiftUI uses the `id` property (either explicitly passed in as the `id` input argument or the `id` property coming from `Identifiable`) to diff the `List` whenever it needs updating so that only the rows affected by the model updated are modified. `id` is also used when deleting rows for instance.